# What is wrong with my js or wasm or something about it? a cannot understend where is a mistake exactly

Tags: javascript, web, compilation, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to porting mkp224o prog to web by using Emscripten and WASM, but cautch error. i try to google it, but everything is about excel and vba. i cant understand is it js or wasm and what is wrong here? i spent a lot of hours trying to build it prog, and finaly i come to the cross wall... what to do now.

```
  wasm streaming compile failed: LinkError: import object field '__memory_base' is not a Number mkp224o.js:1652:16
falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation mkp224o.js:1653:16
failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: LinkError: import object field '__memory_base' is not a Number mkp224o.js:1615:10
Aborted(LinkError: import object field '__memory_base' is not a Number) mkp224o.js:1416:6
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: Aborted(LinkError: import object field '__memory_base' is not a Number)
    abort http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1435
    instantiateArrayBuffer http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1621
    promise callback*instantiateArrayBuffer http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1614
    instantiateAsync http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1654
    promise callback*instantiateAsync/< http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1647
    promise callback*instantiateAsync http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1639
    createWasm http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1676
    <anonymous> http://43tdtgbzu522irytndtrpayedex75wvfqcfbdrohdof3t2iur5gux3qd.onion/mkp224o.js:1869
```

that is sreenshot of error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vv3t2ljx4mejtu3/Screen_shot5.png?dl=0

and that is dropbox folder with test site files:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/elgdplx8xmvp51g/AAC-M0oCrA0_rgWZfrRvMt8na?dl=0

Comment: on desck top it need to to run with words parameters? maybe its trying to make table from empty memory? PS for example for descktop runing you need write:

mkp224o word1 word2 word3
or
mkp224o word1

then prog will brutforsing site key pairs of onion sites which starts from wordN. for example of result is 

word1dkfjfjririeiewjewndsnsdnjvcidoore4494irjdfnfdn.onion

Comment: I try try to generate it one more time. error partly chage the icons https://www.dropbox.com/s/io9v2bmkpc9uc7z/Screen_shot4.png?dl=0

Comment: I change compiler flags to emcc ./mkp224o.o -O1 -o mkp224o.wasm -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1
and error also have changed to LinkError: import object field '__memory_base' is not a Number

Comment: I cant answer the question but i have solved it. I has trying to link the sodium library from the local repo of emscripten, but it must to be in the same folder as a project is. i compile with:em++ --no-entry -s -Wall -s -Wextra -s -Wno-unused-function -s  -Wmissing-prototypes -s -Wstrict-prototypes -s  -DED25519_donna -s -fPIE -s  -DSTATISTICS -s  -DPASSPHRASE -s -DVERSION='"unknown"' -o mkp224o.html main.c.o worker.c.o yaml.c.o vec.c.o cpucount.c.o base32_to.c.o base32_from.c.o base64_to.c.o base64_from.c.o ioutil.c.o keccak.c.o -lpthread ./libsodium.a

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.

Comment: Your comment says that you can't answer the question, but you should be able to answer your own question.  The system here is designed to allow you to do that.

Comment: ok, i will try one more time)

Comment: sorry guys, i can not post the answer normally, i have two minuses last time because i forget to switch my translator to English https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o2kdqz3coibcgo/Screen_shot6.png?dl=0